# How do I compare two strings of different lengths and return false for just 1 invalid char?

Tags: java

```
public boolean setValidColor(String input, String colors) {
    int exists;
    isValidColor = true;
    char[] colorch = colors.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(colorch);
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        exists = Arrays.binarySearch(colorch, input.charAt(i));
        if(exists == -1)
        {
            isValidColor = false;
            break;
        }
    }  
    return isValidColor;
}
```

I'm having trouble comparing two strings of different lengths and returning false at just 1 instance of an invalid input..

For example:
possible colors are RGOPYB and input colors are YZOR. The 'Z' is not a possibility and I need to code to return false but the code keeps returning true. Where am I going wrong?

edit: There is more to this code than just this (doing OOP), this is just a method that I keep running into trouble on.

Comment: Could you rephrase this as ... something that makes sense? You compare `String`s with `String.equals()` ... it would appear you're trying to do something very different than that.

Comment: You are overcomplicating this...

Comment: i believe he is treating the string like a character set, and so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: I would think you can do this in 1-2 lines with a regexp if it just checks validity.

Comment: I tried different ways of comparing. I've done nested for-loops to compare the two strings, and I've tried doing a while-loop. The code I have is just the most recent one I have.

Answer (score 6):

`Arrays.binarySearch` will only return -1 if the value being searched for should be inserted at position 0. For other values that are not found, it returns other negative values. Test for `exist < 0` instead of `exists == -1`.

Comment: So I tried doing that. I didn't mention this, but there are more to the condition that has to be met. For what I am doing I generated a random 4 letter char from the possible list and my input has to be a possible chars and come to true if it matches 4 letter list. Say I have to compare my input, BORG, to BORG and make sure the list has valid chars. It should come out to true but it keeps returning false.

Comment: If you are dealing with only four letter tests, then a binary search is overkill. Just use something like this for your method: `for (int i=input.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) if (colors.indexOf(input.charAt(i)) == -1) return false; return true;`

Answer (score 0):

From java.util.Arrays:
index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(*insertion point*) - 1).
Means your condition should be:

> ```
>    if(exists < 0)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Ted Hopp has found your problem.

---

I'd just like to point out that your current approach (sorting and using binary search) is likely to be *significantly* slower than a simple `O(N^2)` algorithm using `colors.indexOf(input.charAt(i))`.  You can improve things by "hoisting" the creation of the sorted array of characters.  (Or maybe just require the `colors` string to be sorted as a precondition.)  But even with that change, the `indexOf` approach will still be faster if the color array is small enough.

The moral of this is that optimization (especially premature optimization) can make things worse if you don't include a realistic characterization of the expected data.

(Now maybe "RGOPYB" is not indicative of the actual number of colors.  But if that's the case, you ought to tell us ...)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert it into lists. Then you can use retainAll or removeAll and see if the list is empty/the same.

Something like:

```
 List validInput=   input.retainAll(colors);
if(validInput.equals(input)) {
 return true;
} 
return false;
```